# XLwings selecting item on ListBox

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to select items programmatically from a listbox. On VBA I will do:

```
Sheet1.MyListBox.Selected(0) = True
```

Or to deselect

```
Sheet1.MyListBox.Selected(0) = False
```

With XLwings I have been able to easily check if an item is selected by doing:

```
>> wb.Sheets(1).api.MyListBox.Selected(0)
True
```

But if I try to assign a value I get an error:

```
wb.Sheets(1).api.MyListBox.Selected(0) = True
  File "<ipython-input-156-9ef416a5660f>", line 1
    wb.Sheets(1).api.MyListBox.Selected(0) = True
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Hope somebody can help.

PS: I found that if you are in Design Mode (selected on the Excel toolbar) even the first line won't work on Python for some reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comment**: What if ... the method was not implemented? ... use `ListBox.Selected(0) = True` and find it is impossible with xlwings

There is no `ListBox.Selected(Int32)` in the current Library.
Therefore I assume it have to be implemented in `xlwings` to be available.
Using the `.api` Interface you could only use whatever is provided by the Library.

---

> **Question**: select items programmatically from a listbox

```
wb.Sheets(1).api.MyListBox.SetSelected(0, True)
```

> [ListBox.SetSelected Method (Int32, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected.aspx)
>
> Selects or clears the selection for the specified item in a ListBox.
>   Parameters
>   `index` Type: System.Int32
>   The zero-based index of the item in a ListBox to select or clear the selection for.
>   `value` Type: System.Boolean
>   true to select the specified item; otherwise, false.

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick. What if for some reason the method was not implemented? I would then have to use `ListBox.Selected(0) = True` and find it is impossible with xlwings ...

Comment: One can do 'wb.Sheets(1).api.MyListBox.Selected(0)' and get 'True' or 'False' depending on the status of that item. But while on VBA you can assign a value doing 'MyListBox.Selected(0) = True', that is not possible using xlwings. You solved the issue using another method (SetSelected) and that is great as I was not aware it existed! My last comment was a question around the fact of what to do if you find yourself forced to use 'wb.Sheets(1).api.MyListBox.Selected(0) = True'  (because SetSelected does not exists for instance).

Comment: @Yona: Why should you be _**forced**_? The fact that `.Selected(0)` **only** exist in VBA could be _historical_ or _future_, only MS knows why.